# Acesso remoto de pagina via https em rede interna

Tags: wamp, https, wampserver

Segui [esse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARsETkA-pvA) tutorial para instalar o `https` no localhost.

Mas eu gostaria de acessar meus projetos também, só que pela rede, assim como faço usando o `http`

Tentei seguir o mesmo padrão que uso no `httpd.conf`, mas não deu certo.

O comando que uso no `httpd.conf` é:

```
<Directory "D:\wamp\www\filelist">
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Mas sem sucesso!

Comment: Já tentou fazer um redirecionamento para https, usando htaccess?

Comment: mas com o `https` não abre a página

Comment: Qual erro aparece? Tem alguma coisa no log do apache?